# PHP doPost not working. Cant print "saves" after clicking the button

Tags: php

My code is very simple yet I cannot make a doPost request. 
Here is my code below. I am using PHP 5.6.25 or PHP 7.0.10 im not sure. I just recently installed wampp

```
  <?php
   include('db.php');

  if(isset($_REQUEST['btnsave']))
  {
   echo "Saves";  //This is not showing after clicking save
  }
   ?>

  <form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td> Student </td>
      <td><input type="text" name "txtsu_name"> </td>
    </tr>

    <td>Address</td>
      <td><input type="text" name "txtaddress"> </td>
    </tr>

    <td>Status</td>
      <td>
      <select>
        <option value ="1"> Active </option>
        <option value ="0"> Suspend </option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name"btnsave"> </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: I also tried if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
  {
   echo "Saves";  //This is not showing after clicking save
  }
   ?>
STILL dosent work

Answer (score 2):

You pretty missing all equal sign in name properties not just bntsave

```
name="anything"
```

So, please update all input fields.
and add name to select also:

```
<select name="isActive">
```

Comment: @Zeaaan, This is a much more relevant answer. You're missing all `=` signs after `name`.